# Shortcut for deleting docker image and all containers using it?

Tags: docker

During development i often come to the point where I need to delete a docker image, but also to first stop and remove all containers using it. So essentially I am doing:

- stop containers for the image
- remove containers
- remove image

Any shortcut for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use simple bash script for this

```
#!/bin/bash
docker stop $(docker ps --filter ancestor=$1 --format="{{.ID}}")
docker rm $(docker ps -a --filter ancestor=$1 --format="{{.ID}}")
docker rmi $1
```

Just call it:

```
./remove-img.sh <image-name>
```

Comment: This script fails when there are no containers dependent on the image.

Comment: Strangely, I tried delete image without containers - it just printed `docker: "stop" requires a minimum of 1 argument.` and `docker: "rm" requires a minimum of 1 argument.` but image was successfully removed.